# Java apache commons collections primitives import issues

Tags: java

I have commons-primitives-1.0.jar added as external executable jar on my eclipse.
So i am able to `import org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayUnsignedShortList;`

and I have a function

```
private void start() {

    _nexts = new ArrayList(_iterators.size());

    for (int i = 0, m = _iterators.size(); i < m; i++) {
        _nexts.add(null);
    }
    _nextSet = new BitSet(_iterators.size());
    _prevFrom = new ArrayUnsignedShortList(); < ---give me error here
}
```

it says,

> The constructor ArrayUnsignedShortList() is not visible

I am not quite sure how to go about fixing this error because when i looked at the `ArraysUnsignedShortList.java`, it does have constructor.

Help?

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/ArrayUnsignedShortList.html

public ArrayUnsignedShortList()
Construct an empty list with the default initial capacity.

^ so i should be able to call it..

Comment: @rkosegi It is, according to the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/ArrayUnsignedShortList.html#ArrayUnsignedShortList\(\)).

Comment: Not necessarily related, but what's the declared type of `_prevFrom`?

Comment: @Paul, that documentation says the constructor is public. So he should be able to use it.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi You're wrong - the constructor is public, so he shouldn't be disallowed from using it.

Comment: @Pual, LOL, that is what my comment says.

Comment: @Pural yes it is decalred. yes the doc says the constructor is public so i should be able to see it. hmm which is why i am so confused

Comment: @ealeon I'm wondering *what type* `_prevFrom` is.

Comment: @Paul ArrayUnsignedIntList _prevFrom

Comment: @ealeon So you're trying to assign an `ArrayUnsignedShortList` to an `ArrayUnsignedIntList`?

Comment: i just want to be able to instantiate it first. but it does not let me do that. ArrayUnsignedIntList _prevFrom = new ArrayUnsignedIntList();

Comment: What happens when you ctrl + click on the constructor? Does it take you to org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayUnsignedShortList?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, unsure you have the correct library, with the correct import, and that nothing can interfere in your code :

If using Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-primitives</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-primitives</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Import :

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayUnsignedShortList;
```

Code :

```
ArrayUnsignedShortList myArray = new ArrayUnsignedShortList();
```

Comment: hmm i m not quite sure why i have this error. your sugesstion does not fix my problem.

Comment: Then either you are not using the correct version (custom package?) and the one you are using does not have a `public` no-arg constructor, either eclipse is failing and reporting an error which it isn't supposed to report. I can confirm that everything works fine with the version provided by maven (public repo). I'm using Netbeans btw.

Answer (score 0):

Download Jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsprimitives10jar.htm)

Import the jar to your project and use this ,, Working fine.

```
ArrayUnsignedShortList obj = new ArrayUnsignedShortList();
```

Comment: grrr this should work but it just wont. I should not be even able to import if it does not see it but i can import fine. i just dont understand :(

Comment: What is happening yaar ?How did you import this jar to your project ?

Comment: i did ArrayUnsignedShortList mine = new ArrayUnsignedShortList(); still says its not visible with your jar. i am guessing the problem is not the jar since you can work with it. idk where to pinpoint the issue

Comment: @TheUnlucky, jar is already in the classpath because he is able to use it.